# Disable Word 2010 commands on a document level

Tags: vba, ms-word

We want to disable any and all formatting and insertion commands in Word except for bold and italic in all documents that are created from a certain template. It should not be possible to change styles, insert anything but text, or change character formatting at all (except for the aforementioned bold and italic formats). Is there a way to achieve this?

Maybe it would be possible to disable these commands with a VBA autostart macro in the template?

Comment: AFAIK you can only use the document-protection via password to protect it against "editing" for example, but certain formatting-options... i guess you have to solve that restriction on a higher level (OSI 8 maybe)

Comment: Not really. It's possible do most of this with a single *Plain Text Content Control* in the doc and restrict formatting to **Filling in Forms** only. But even this CC will take other types of character formating, like underline and color.

Comment: I have been reading up on this, and it seems this is possible with RibbonX. I will post the answer as soon as I manage to find out how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to hook the `WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)` event and catch any change that is not a character, bold format or italic format. I guess it would be a fair amount of coding to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this with RibbonX. For example, to disable the bold command, add this RibbonX XML to the document or template:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <commands>
        <command idMso="Bold" enabled="false"/>
    </commands>
</customUI>
```

Of course, the user can still paste bold text.

Comment: Unfortunately, that just hides the problem a little, it doesn't stop it. Not only can a user paste bold text, they can format via the keyboard by selecting something and the typing Ctrl+B.

Comment: @Otaku: That is not correct. By disabling the commands with RibbonX (not just the UI elements), the command itself is disabled. The user cannot use it by keyboard shortcut, menu item, or in any other way. Using this method, we achieved our goal of preventing all unwanted editing. We did need to hook into the paste event, though.

Comment: Interesting, I stand corrected. Thanks for following up on this.